# Spring Security + LDAP always returns BadCredentialsException

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I have been trying to configure Spring Security to work with LDAP with little success.

I have the following configuration beans:

```
@Bean
public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {

    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("go.com.mt", "LDAP://CORPORATE.INTRA");
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper());
    return provider;
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {
    UserDetailsContextMapper contextMapper = new AttributesLDAPUserDetailsContextMapper();
    return contextMapper;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
}
```

I tried creating a custom mapper as suggested by many answers here on stack overflow that sets every authority to ROLE_USER

```
public class AttributesLDAPUserDetailsContextMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {
    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations dirContextOperations, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authority) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (GrantedAuthority granted : authority) {
            if (true) {
                mappedAuthorities.add(() -> "ROLE_USER");
            } else if(granted.getAuthority().equalsIgnoreCase("MY ADMIN GROUP")) {
                mappedAuthorities.add(() -> "ROLE_ADMIN");
            }
        }
        return new User(username, "", mappedAuthorities);
    }

    @Override
    public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails userDetails, DirContextAdapter dirContextAdapter) {

    }
}
```

When I try authenticating with an existing user and an incorrect password I get the following message:

```
[apr-8080-exec-6] ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid
[apr-8080-exec-6] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Thu Aug 20 07:31:59 CEST 2015, principal=samantha.catania, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException, message=Bad credentials}]
```

meaning that the active directory is being working correctly  but when I try to authenticate with correct credentials I get the following message:

```
[pr-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Ignoring PartialResultException
[pr-8080-exec-10] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Thu Aug 20 07:32:05 CEST 2015, principal=samantha.catania, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException, message=Bad credentials}]
```

Any ideas how to fix this please?

Comment: Check if Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authority is empty or null. Lemme know.

Comment: I added logs to both of the mapper methods but they're never being printed. I also added breakpoints and it's never stopping there @.@

Comment: Where and which mapper methods.. Can you be a bit more precice... A simple if-else loop to check if the list of grantedauthority is null or not i what i want to know.

Comment: After I updated and set the DNs the mapper started being called. Seems like the error was occurring before the mapping was to take place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seemed to be because `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`  was "guessing" the DNs using the domain. Updating `spring-security-ldap` to the latests version made available a [new constructor with 3 parameters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html#ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) where the last one allows you to specify the DNs. After that the mapper started being called successfully and the authentication went through.

I would like to thank everyone that contributed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the setting the java environment property "java.naming.referral" to "follow" (either in code at startup, or via an argument to the JVM -Djava.naming.referral=follow.

Do you get a stack trace, or could you print the BadCredentialsException?

This is very similar to an issue I was having with AD, where the problem was with how AD handles referrals and this would generate errors during data retrieval.

From what you have posted I expect the exception is generated in [ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java line 323](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.0.x/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java#L323), which would point to the same issue.